# loop over directories in cshell

Tags: shell, foreach, csh

I am trying to loop over directories in a path using csh. I am trying this code.

```
    #!/bin/csh
    set z=`/a/b/c/`
    foreach i (`$z`)
     echo $i
    end
```

It returns,

```
    /a/b/c/: Permission denied.
```

I am able to do it in bash and python. But I need it to be done in csh.

Comment: Replace the backticks with single quotes.

Comment: its giving me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used:

```
#!/bin/csh
set z="/a/b/c/"
foreach i (`ls -d $z`)
 echo $i
end
```

and it worked.